# Have any Freeman of the land applications been successful in court?

Tags: united-states, law

I've been reading about various groups purporting to be [Freeman-on-the-land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemen_on_the_land), which believe that contractual ties between the government and these people are only valid if the people consent to them.  However, despite digging quite deep, I have not found a successful defence of such matters.  [Wikipedia's citation for a lack of legal success](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemen_on_the_land) only gives examples of failures, but does not in fact make any claims about the success of the legal argument.

**Has a Freeman-on-the-land argument ever been successful in court?**

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some examples](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/883) of places where this claim is being made.

Comment: I think this is a notable question.  There has been a relatively significant amount of mainstream media coverage on the subject, and [Wikipedia's citation for the OP's claim does not in fact answer the question](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2011/nov/18/freeman-land-strategy-bullet-debt).  The question should be edited to include relevant links and background, though.

Comment: I edited the question to add relevant links and a bit more context.

Comment: If something "only gives examples of failures" I think we can say that's a claim about the success of the legal argument.

Comment: This is asking us to prove a negative. We can cite plenty of learned authorities explaining why it will never be a successful defence, but to prove it has never happened we would need to check every court case in the history of the world.

Comment: Is "Freeman on the Land" the latest iteration of Sovereign Citizens?

Comment: @Shadur: Wikipedia says maybe.

Comment: @DJClayworth: We could use the technique of relying on an expert. However, Wikipedia already does that in a couple of places, so that wouldn't be adding anything.