# Are American courts and federal agencies foreign-controlled private corporations?

Tags: united-states, law

A colleague recently shared [An Open Letter to Sheriff Ward of Harney County Oregon - and to All County Sheriffs in America from Judge Anna](http://www.examiner.com/article/hammond-case-open-letter-to-all-county-sheriffs-america-by-judge-anna)

[This letter](http://annavonreitz.com/openlettertosheriffward.pdf) makes a number of claims, among which:

- The "DEPARTMENT OF JUSTICE" is a private subcontractor used by the federal government.
- "US district courts" are also private subcontractors associated with states only insofar as they lie within certain geographical boundaries.

To what degree are these and other similar government functions "privatized"?

Comment: In my opinion, the claims should be better addressed separately, but they're mostly ludicrous.

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30970/have-any-freeman-of-the-land-applications-been-successful-in-court

Comment: Here's the [full actual letter](http://annavonreitz.com/openlettertosheriffward.pdf). There are other letters on her site.

Comment: This is probably biased, but it really seems that the US come up with these kind of quacks in much higher numbers than other places around the world...